# spring batch about JdbcCursorItemReader

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I have got a problem when I use JdbcCursorItemReader

org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: Unexpected cursor position change

I've set dataSource, sql ,rowmapper,fetchsize ..

and also did not use multithread, anyone helps me?

Comment: Post code, configuration, stacktraces, logging. See http://sscce.org/

Comment: possible duplicate of [InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: Unexpected cursor position change](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20387864/invaliddataaccessresourceusageexception-unexpected-cursor-position-change)

Answer (score 1):

Try to disable verifyCursorPosition property. Check if ti does meet your requirments as this parameter allows verification of cursor position after current row is processed by RowMapper or RowCallbackHandler when activated.
You did not post any code. Here an [example using jdbccursoritemreader](https://tutoref.com/tag/jdbccursoritemreader/).

Answer (score 0):

As the post that bellabax points out, this exception is thrown when the RowMapper manipulates the cursor position.  This occurs because of the way restart processing is set up.  On restart, we skip to the last record that was processed.  If the cursor is moved without the framework knowing, we'll restart in the wrong position.